# Advantages of Java NIO in blocking mode versus traditional I/O?

Tags: java, performance, io, nio, blocking

I have pretty much already decided not to use asynchronous, non-blocking Java NIO. The complexity versus benefit is very questionable in general, and I think it's not worth it in this project particularly.

But most of what I read about NIO, and comparisons with older java.io.* focuses on non-blocking, asynchronous NIO versus thread-per-connection synchronous I/O using java.io.*. However, NIO can be used in synchronous, blocking, thread-per-connection mode, which is rarely discussed it seems.

Here's the question: Is there any performance advantage of synchronous, blocking NIO versus traditional synchronous, blocking I/O (java.io.*)? Both would be thread-per-connection. How does the complexity compare?

Note that this is a general question, but at the moment I am primarily concerned with TCP socket communication.

Comment: +1 for caution - complexity should be scary.

Comment: you can't use per thread connection with blocking operations, you need 2 threads per connections.

Comment: (continue) ...unless you are doing just request/response stuff. If you use socket.getInputStream.read() you lose all the benefits of the direct buffers but the impl. still uses selectors to block on the read. I can't think why (and on which OS) it should have benefits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4752404/32453 mentions NIO in blocking mode to be faster...

Answer (score 23):

An advantage of NIO over "traditional" IO is that NIO can use [direct buffers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#direct) that allow the OS to use DMA for some operations (e.g. reading from a network connection directly into a memory-mapped file) and thereby avoid copying data to intermediate buffers.

If you're moving large amounts of data in a scenario where this technique does avoid copy operations that would otherwise be performed, this can have a big impact on performance.

Comment: +1 The NIO package uses a system of `Buffer`s rather than `InputStream`s and `OutputStream`s (what java.io.* uses).

Answer (score 11):

It basically boils down the number of concurrent connections and how busy those connections are.  Blocking (standard thread per connection) is faster, both in latency and throughput (about twice as fast for a simple echo server).  So if your system can cope with maintaining a thread for each connection (<1000 connections as a rule of thumb) go for the blocking approach.  If you have lots of mostly idle connections (e.g. Comet long poll requests or IMAP idle connections) then switching to a non-blocking architecture could help scale your system.

Comment: I agree with it depends on how many concurrent connections you want to process. My threshold would be 100 not 1000. 1000 threads is a lot of threads for an app to hold. (+1)

Comment: @Michael Barker Why is blocking thread per connection faster in terms of latency and throughput?

Comment: Not sure, probably a shorter/simpler kernel transition.

Answer (score 0):

I can not speak to the technology in particular, but it is not unusual for asynchronous libraries to provide synchronous operations to facilitate in debugging.

For instance if you are having problems you can eliminate the asynchronous portions of the logic without rewriting your entire process. This is especially helpful since synchronous processes are typically much easier to work with.